# Export SQL Azure db to blob - Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport : Cannot convert AzureStorageContainer to AzureStorageContainer

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I am using [this code found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261258/start-azuresqldatabaseexport-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-obje) on stack , and all connections are correct.

```
Import-Module Azure 
Import-Module Azure.Storage

Get-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionName “Production” | Select-AzureRmSubscription

# Username for Azure SQL Database server
$ServerLogin = "username"

# Password for Azure SQL Database server
$serverPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "abcd" -AsPlainText -Force


# Establish credentials for Azure SQL Database Server 
$ServerCredential = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($ServerLogin, $serverPassword) 

# Create connection context for Azure SQL Database server
$SqlContext = New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext -FullyQualifiedServerName “myspecialsqlserver.database.windows.net” -Credential $ServerCredential

$StorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName 'prodwad' -StorageAccountKey 'xxxxx'
$Container = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name 'automateddbbackups' -Context $StorageContext

$exportRequest = Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport -SqlConnectionContext $SqlContext -StorageContainer $Container -DatabaseName 'Users' -BlobName 'autobackupotest.bacpac' -Verbose -Debug
```

I am getting this error. I have spent hours on this.

```
Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport : Cannot bind parameter 'StorageContainer'. Cannot convert the 
"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer" value of type 
"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer" to type 
"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageContainer".
At line:31 char:99
+ ... SqlConnectionContext $SqlContext -StorageContainer $Container -Databa ...
+                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Database.Cmdlet.StartAzureSqlDatabaseExport
```

I am using AzureRM 3.8.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your description and codes, If you want to start a new sqldatabase export.I suggest you could try below codes. It will work well.

```
$subscriptionId = "YOUR AZURE SUBSCRIPTION ID"

Login-AzureRmAccount
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

# Database to export
$DatabaseName = "DATABASE-NAME"
$ResourceGroupName = "RESOURCE-GROUP-NAME"
$ServerName = "SERVER-NAME"
$serverAdmin = "ADMIN-NAME"
$serverPassword = "ADMIN-PASSWORD" 
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $serverPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $serverAdmin, $securePassword

# Generate a unique filename for the BACPAC
$bacpacFilename = $DatabaseName + (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + ".bacpac"

# Storage account info for the BACPAC
$BaseStorageUri = "https://STORAGE-NAME.blob.core.windows.net/BLOB-CONTAINER-NAME/"
$BacpacUri = $BaseStorageUri + $bacpacFilename
$StorageKeytype = "StorageAccessKey"
$StorageKey = "YOUR STORAGE KEY"

$exportRequest = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName `
  -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -StorageKeytype $StorageKeytype -StorageKey $StorageKey -StorageUri $BacpacUri `
  -AdministratorLogin $creds.UserName -AdministratorLoginPassword $creds.Password

$exportRequest

# Check status of the export
Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $exportRequest.OperationStatusLink
```

Then you could use Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus to see the details information, like below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem after updating some powershell packages which I do not remember exactly. After the update my scripts started to fail.

My solution is :

1. Install the latest [AzureRM from nuget via powershell](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM/)
2. Use the other overload of [Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/start-azuresqldatabaseexport?view=azuresmps-4.0.0) which utilizes the parameters

   -**StorageContainerName** and -**StorageContext**  rather than -**StorageContainer**

It looks like if you pass the parameters to the function it will create the container object internally without crashing.